# Delphi TidSNTP Android

Tags: android, delphi, indy

I'm using TidSNTP to get the adjustment time between a time server and the local clock time. On Windows, it does what I expect:

1. Convert the time server's date time from UTC to local time
2. Subtract my clock's time from the localized time server's date time

However, on my android device, something different happens:

1. The server's date time returns as the UTC time, not local time
2. The adjustment time returns as my local offset from (UTC * 2) + the adjustment time

Has anyone else experienced this? Suggestions?

```
SNTP := TIdSNTP.Create(Self);
try
  SNTP.ReceiveTimeout := 5000;
  SNTP.Host := 'time.nist.gov';
  try
    DateTime := SNTP.DateTime;
    TimeOffset := SNTP.AdjustmentTime;
    SNTPFailed := False;
  except
    SNTPFailed := True;
  end;
  SNTP.Active := False;
finally
  SNTP.DisposeOf;
  SNTP := Nil;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually sync your clock using `TIdSNTP`, you should be calling `TIdSNTP.SyncTime()`, which is meant to handle the offsets for you.

That being said, I think `TIdSNTP.DateTime` is supposed to be expressed in local time, not UTC.  Internally, the date/time values are adjusted using Indy's `IdGlobalProtocols.TimeZoneBias()` function, which returns `-OffetFromUTC()` on all platforms except Unix-based systems (which includes Android), where it instead calculates the offset manually using the same logic that `OffsetFromUTC()` returns, thus the result is the reverse of what `-OffsetFromUTC()` would return.  That seems a bit odd to me.  `TimeZoneBias()` should probably be using `-OffsetFromUTC()` on all platforms unconditionally.

Try editing Indy's `IdGlobalProtocols.pas` file to make `TimeZoneBias()` return `-OffsetFromUTC()` on all platforms, then recompile Indy (or at least add the edited file to your project) and see if your problem goes away:

```
function TimeZoneBias: TDateTime;
{$IFDEF USE_INLINE} inline; {$ENDIF}
begin
  Result := -OffsetFromUTC;
end;
```

Comment: Correct Remy. In the Android context, .SyncTime does adjust the time on my Android, but only to within 0.14 - 0.17 of a second. (checked through repeated adjustments and calculations) The .adjustmentTime is a number that doesn't make sense to me (-4 hours) when I'm in a GMT+ 2 timezone.

Comment: 0.14-0.17 of a second sounds about right.  [RFC 2030](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2030) (which `TIdSNTP` is based on) states: "*This allows a simple calculation to determine the propagation delay between the server and client and to **align the local clock generally within a few tens of milliseconds** relative to the server*". As for the `AdjustmentTime`, it just returns the `FLocalClockOffset` member, which is calculated as `FLocalClockOffset := ((FReceiveTimestamp - FOriginateTimestamp) + (FTransmitTimestamp - FDestinationTimestamp)) / 2;`, per RFC 2030 Section 5.

Comment: If you are seeing values that are off by 2-6 hours, then that goes back to my comment that maybe Indy's `TimeZoneBias()` function is returning the wrong value on Android. Did you make the code change I recommended in my answer?  Did it make any difference over the original code?

Comment: I modified the idGlobalProtocols.pas as you suggested and added it to my Android project. With the change, The idSNTP1.AdjustmentTime is now < 0.5 seconds, instead of 0.1666 of a day - and idSNTP1.DateTime is also within 0.5 seconds of now (and not 0.1666 of day behind). Thanks!